# Build extremely slow after upgrade to Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After upgraded to Xcode 12, the build progress will last for about 10 minutes when the target is a real device. But it's only need less then 1 minutes in Xcode 11 with the same project and the same device.

When i check the build log, i found the signing progress cost a lot of time

> Showing All Messages sent 187539 bytes  received 70 bytes  375218.00
> bytes/sec
>
> total size is 188006  speedup is 1.00
>
> Code Signing
> /Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/LCNetwork.framework
> with Identity -
>
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -
> --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/LCNetwork.framework'
>
> /Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/LCNetwork.framework:
> replacing existing signature
>
> rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/"
> --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules"
> "/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.framework"
> "/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks"
>
> building file list ... done
>
> MBProgressHUD.framework/
>
> MBProgressHUD.framework/MBProgressHUD
>
> MBProgressHUD.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
>
> sent 173429 bytes  received 70 bytes  346998.00 bytes/sec
>
> total size is 173884  speedup is 1.00
>
> Code Signing
> /Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/MBProgressHUD.framework
> with Identity -
>
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -
> --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/MBProgressHUD.framework'
>
> /Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks/MBProgressHUD.framework:
> replacing existing signature
>
> rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/"
> --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules"
> "/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MJRefresh/MJRefresh.framework"
> "/Users/cc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkDaily-abnizdojrgeyrjayljkajexbcxcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarkDaily.app/Frameworks"
>
> building file list ... done
>
> MJRefresh.framework/
>
> MJRefresh.framework/MJRefresh
>
> MJRefresh.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder, sometimes that can help.

Answer (score 1):

I found there is 'replacing sign' in the log. So it can be caused by duplicated sign.

And then remove `Pods` directory and reinstall all pods via `pod install`. Then build speed is normal.